# Using toggle to click and element and show/hide the element right below it?

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

[image]

I want to make `ul.children` show and hide by clicking the another like above (Bars).

It should only show/hide the one below because the page is full of unordered lists with the same structure.

So I'm stuck here:

```
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item > a').click(function() {
  ???
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item > a').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("ul.children").toggle();
});
```

should work i think

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

e.g.

```
$(this).next('.children').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#wpbdp-categories > .wpbdp-categories > li.cat-item > a').toggle(
    function() { $(this).next().show() },
    function() { $(this).next().hide() }
);
```

the easiest way..

**Edit:**

`.toggle()` handles the click event so u dont need to define a click event for it.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> The .toggle() method binds a handler for the click event, so the rules
>   outlined for the triggering of click apply here as well.